# What is a good aproach handling interface specific methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say I have:

```
public class Buff {
  ... code ...
}
```

Then I'm implementing triggers for my Buff

```
public interface IBuffOnActionTrigger {
   void OnPlayerAction(Player p);
}

public interface IBuffOnPlayerDie {
   void OnPlayerDie(Player p);
}
```

So now I can implement those methods on a buff.

I have the following method:

```
public void TriggerBuffs<TriggerType>(Player p) {
    p.Buffs.Where(b => b is TriggerType).ForEach(b => b.<CALLMETHOD>);
}
```

In this case, I'm using a Switch case

```
switch typeof(TriggerType):
   case IBuffOnPlayerDie:
      buff.OnPlayerDie(p);
   ... etc
```

But I was looking a way to do this more elegantly. What would be a good design for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way of triggering is simply to have different methods for it

```
public void TriggerActions(Player p)
{
    foreach (var buff in p.Buffs.OfType<IBuffOnActionTrigger>()) {
        buff.OnPlayerAction(p);
    }
}

public void TriggerPlayerDie(Player p)
{
    foreach (var buff in p.Buffs.OfType<IBuffOnPlayerDie>()) {
        buff.OnPlayerDie(p);
    }
}
```

`OfType<T>()` filters the Buffs implementing T and casts them to `T`, making it easy to call the corresponding method.

Note that generic type parameters are always resolved at compile time, i.e., they don't give you a dynamic behavior at run time. So `void TriggerBuffs<TriggerType>(Player p)` does not allow you to select the trigger dynamically.

If you want to do this, then use an enum

```
public enum TriggerType
{
    None,
    Action,
    PlayerDie
}
```

now you can call different trigger types dynamically:

```
public void Trigger(TriggerType triggerType, Player p)
{
    switch (triggerType) {
        case TriggerType.None:
            break;
        case TriggerType.Action:
            TriggerActions(p);
            break;
        case TriggerType.PlayerDie:
            TriggerPlayerDie(p);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```